# Do I need a string in this function?

Tags: parsing, swift

For some reason I'm getting 4 errors in this code:

1. Unknown type name 'func'
2. expected function body after function declarator (which I thought I included)
3. type specifier missing defaults to 'int'
4. expected ')'

Here's the code for the function I'm trying to write, which is supposed to add a vote to a poll choice when the button for that choice is pressed:

```
func addVote(countOption1: String) -> String {
    let result = countOption1 += 1
    return result
}
```

What am I missing from this code to execute that function, and how can I add the name of the choice that the vote is stored for? Again all votes need to be stored on my Parse.com account and I'm trying to return the result for each poll.  The button I'm trying to add above is just for one option, but will be in a poll with 2-4 additional options.

Comment: Those sound like errors that a C compiler would generate, yet you are showing Swift code.  Are you sue you have your XCode project setup to compile as Swift?  Also why are you string what appears to be an integer count in a string?

Comment: Or maybe your error in typing is above the function decleration and smart swift compiler gives you errors about your perfectly correct function

Answer (score 1):

I think while creating a project you forget to select programming language as a swift so make a new project and set programming language as swift and try this code. I think this is going to work on that.

Comment: OK, so there's nothing wrong with my code as it's written in Swift? I don't need to add anything else to it to send vote responses to my Parse.com database and to have poll results return?

Comment: I can't change the language, I'm importing an Xcode project file from Parse.com and that automatically sets it to Objective-C. I have no clue how to import the Parse Starter Project file into a project I've already started on Xcode. I've tried the instructions they provided for "existing project" and that doesn't work either.